# Changing the state of a button HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in the body of my HTML which acts as a show/hide button and it is styled via CSS. However I only have the option to title the button once i.e 'Read more.." but after the button has been selected I would like it to change to 'Read less'. Here is the code I am using:

```
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" 
   onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none')        
   {document.getElementById('spoiler')   
   .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler')  
   .style.display='none'}">Read more...
</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code..?

Comment: are you trying to show and hide everytime a button is click?

Comment: whoa, you should put that javascript inside a function instead of directly in the onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<button title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="func()" id="but">Read more...</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
```

JS:

```
   function func(){

           if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=="none"){
           document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display="block";
           document.getElementById('but').innerHTML="Read less...";
           }
           else{
           document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display='none';
           document.getElementById('but').innerHTML="Read more...";
           }
           }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5wYE/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get out of the habit of bundling JavaScript inline as HTML attributes. Look into DOM-scripting centrally from your JS scripts rather than in your HTML.

The essence of what you need to do is to query something each time the button is clicked, and act accordingly. The visibility of the spoiler area, for example.

(Note, you will need to give your button an ID, e.g. `mybutton`, for this:)

```
document.querySelector('#mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var
    spoiler = document.querySelector('#spoiler'),
    showing = spoiler.style.display != 'none';
    spoiler.style.display = showing ? 'none' : 'block';
    this.textContent = 'Read '+(showing ? 'more' : 'less');
}, false);
```

So on click, we interrogate the `display` style of `#spoiler`. If it's showing, we hide it, and if it's hidden, we show it, updating the button text accordingly.

Comment: You are missing a plus (`+`) at: `'Read ' + (showing ? 'more' : 'less')`, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<button id="btn" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="readmore()">Read More...</button>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">spoiler text</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function readmore(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var spoiler = document.getElementById('spoiler');

    if(spoiler.style.display=='none') {
        spoiler.style.display = '';
        btn.innerHTML = "Read Less ...";
    } else {
        spoiler.style.display = 'none';
        btn.innerHTML = "Read More ...";
    }   
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/rN2L9/)**.